# jQuery change event is not working with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, materialize

```
<tr>
  <td class="large-width">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ${todo.isCompleted ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
        <span class="text">${todo.item}</span>
      </label>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
   $('#checkbox').change(function(){
     console.log('something');
   });
</script>
```

I can see that checkbox is changing it's state, but Change event is not working. I also tried on('change') and click events - they're not working either. By the way, I'm using materializecss.

Comment: you code works .. does your console shows any error ?

Comment: make sure to insert you jQuery before javascript tags.

Comment: Yes.Now, I tried in JSFiddle and it works. But in my project it's not working. Seems like I'm missing something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to call below jQuery methods to working code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // jQuery methods go here... });
```

OR

```
$(function(){ // jQuery methods go here... });
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="large-width">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ${todo.isCompleted ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
        <span class="text">${todo.item}</span>
      </label>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#checkbox').change(function(){
     console.log('something');
   }); });
</script>
```

Comment: The second is preferred since the first is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Keep it inside document ready

```js
<script>
$(function(ready){
   $('#checkbox').change(function(){
     console.log('something');
   });
});
</script>
```